# Overwrite data when multiple jobs run at the same time

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, quartz-scheduler

I have a **ScheduleJob.java** that implements Job Quartz, and there are about 100 jobs running at the same time every 1 minute.
I am facing the problem when 100 jobs run together, that is when the first job is run and the following jobs run together in parallel, then the first job gets the data **mapBalance = 400**, but because it has to handle Many of the conditions below have not been completed, so the following jobs also go to get **mapBalance and set = 3000**, then the first job gets mapBalance (to print out or process data), then the following jobs overwrite the data into **mapBalance**.

How to make multiple jobs run at the same time but still get different data for each job?

```
public class ScheduleJob implements Job{

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        Long betId = Long.parseLong(context.getJobDetail().getKey().getName());
        
        Map<String, String> mapBalance = AccessBOUtils.getBalance(betId);
        System.out.println("mapBalance:"+mapBalance);
        
        /***
         * code
         */
         
        System.out.println("get Balance by betId: " + mapBalance.get("demoBalance"));
        
    }

}
```

```
mapBalance:{availableBalance="0.0", demoBalance="400"}
mapBalance:{availableBalance="0.0", demoBalance="1679"}
mapBalance:{availableBalance="0.0", demoBalance="3000"}

get Balance by betId: 3000
get Balance by betId: 3000
get Balance by betId: 3000
```

Comment: First thing are those jobs interdependent? then if you run start them at the same time it is a problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. You run 100x the same job at the same time, with the same arguments, they are bound to try do the same thing. You seem to have left out the important part: what is your code doing with the `mapBalance`

Comment: in static AccessBOUtils i took the Map out of the method and now it can no longer be overwritten, thanks for your feedback